# Load Balancer with Zookeeper

Tags: load-balancing, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to create a Load Balancer to be in front of a Zookeeper 3.4.6 cluster. When I do that the cluster works well but an exception is thrown:

> WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
>   EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket
>   
> at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
>   
> at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
>   
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

It means that Zookeeper is understanding Load Balancer as a client and it's tryong to stablish a connection with it. But the Load Balancer just pings TCP 2181 and comes out.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to use a load balancer between your ZooKeeper cluster and clients?

When you give your clients a ZooKeeper connection string in the form of multiple endpoints like this: "server1,server2,server3...", the clients will pick one of the servers and switch over in case of failure. This way, if all your clients have the same ZooKeeper endpoints string, you will end up with a balanced pool.

If you put a standard load balancer between the clients and the server, it can cause failures like this. A load balancer doesn't play well with the way ZooKeeper expects its clients to behave. A client needs to maintain an open TCP connection to a specific server it has a session on, sending periodic heartbeats.

There are certain limitations to the way ZooKeeper clients load balance themselves (e.g. connections won't rebalance in case of server restarts), but fixing these limitations would require a ZooKeeper protocol aware load balancing logic, probably as part of the client implementation.

Comment: The purpose of using load balancer is to be able to scale zookeeper without need to change the clients configuration. Is it possible any way?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure. The current stable 3.4.x version doesn't support it, clients need the static connection string. There are new reconfiguration features coming in 3.5 but not sure when that is going to be available.
As I said before, if you put anything between your ZK clients and Server that would add this functionality, you'd have to be really careful not to mess with the way ZK expects the client connections to behave, e.g. maintaining the heartbeat.

Comment: thanks for this information, do you have any evidence from ZK page saying this ? I mean that ZK 3.4.x doesnt support to work behind a LB (clusterIP and ip table, nothing else)... Because I have that production environment, I want to change it because obviously ZK clients and server has their own protocol handling failures, latency and "confidence" between them, but has worked somehow although with lot of messages lost, but no clear evidence of an error from ZK server or client...

Comment: "with a lot of messages lost" is not "working". That is broken.